# Regular Expression that needs to match three exact digits in a four digit number

Tags: regex

The regular expression that I am trying to create should match all numbers that contain three '8's in any 4 digit number. The regular expression that I have only matches the first 10 numbers out of the list of 15 numbers.  Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

```
\b[0-9]*(?:8[0-9]*[0-9]?8|8[0-9]*[0-9]?8|8[0-9]*[0-9]?8)\b
```

Test data:

```
8088 8188 8288 8388 8488 8808 8818 8828 8838 8848 8880 8881 8882 8883 8884
```

The last five numbers should also match, but don't.

Comment: Try `\b(?=(?:[0-79]*8){3}[0-79]*\b)\d{4}\b` or `\b(?=\d{4}\b)(?:[0-79]*8){3}[0-79]*\b`

Comment: or `\b(?=(?:\d*8){3})\d{4}\b`

Comment: The immediate problem is that you allow the first digit to be any digit.

Comment: It does not need to patch 8888. Wiktor solution worked perfect. Thank you all for your help and explanations.

Comment: Can there be other numbers of arbitrary length in the input? Else, please  consider removing the "in a four digit number" requirement to make the question unambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's guaranteed that the number is a **four-digit** number, then you can try the following:

```js
\b8*[0-79]8*\b
```

To analyze what each part matches, you can check using,

```js
\b(8*)[0-79](8*)\b
```

Comment: The `\b8*[0-79]8*\b` regex [matches](https://regex101.com/r/xZ8AmU/3) `84888` and `8888888488888` numbers, not just 4-digit numbers with three `8`s.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
\b(?=\d{4}\b)(?:[0-79]*8){3}[0-79]*\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xZ8AmU/2).

*Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?=\d{4}\b)` - there must be 4 digits immediately on the right and they should be followed with a word boundary
- `(?:[0-79]*8){3}` - three occurrences of any 0 or more digits but `8` and then `8`
- `[0-79]*` - any 0 or more digits but `8`
- `\b` - word boundary.

Comment: What are the strengths of this solution compared to the currently accepted one which at least is more concise and accessible?

Comment: @sindri_baldur It is correct while [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64318970/3832970) [does not meet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64318691/regular-expression-that-needs-to-match-three-exact-digits-in-a-four-digit-number/64319124?noredirect=1#comment113735479_64318970) the requirements.

Comment: I guess the OP only had 4-digits input in mind. But generalisibility is definitely good.

Comment: This is a good answer, the [0-79] also prevents unnecessary backtracking. ++

Answer (score -1):

This should do it. This will match any of the 4 patterns.

```
([\d888]|[8\d88]|[88\d8]|[888\d])
```

You may want to add a check for the delimiter (in your example the space) as this pattern will match across the spaces giving you many more results

Comment: The square brackets are wrong. Probably review the [Stack Overflow `regex` tag info page](/help/regex/info) for this and other common beginner mistakes.

Comment: @tripleee link is broken

Comment: Sorry, try again: [regex](/tags/regex/info)

Answer (score -2):

`\b(\d?8{3}\d?)\b`

- this makes the first and last digit in the word bound optional, use
  either `?` or `{0,1}`
- add quantifier to your eight to have exactly
  number of eights you need `{3}`
- replace `[0-9]` with `\d` as
  **D**igit for brewity
- supposed you have only numbers of length 4. Otherwise use an alternative without optional digits: `\b(\d8{3}|8{3}\d)\b`

Comment: This only matches adjacent 8:s.